# Complete product/solution for managing user authorization for .NET

Tags: .net, authorization

At the end, it turns out we can not use AD for managing users in groups (don't ask why). I'm looking for .NET based solution with SQL storage to manage users in groups, and API which I could use in MVC. It should have some kind of user interface to manage groups, etc..

What I have checked so far:

- AzMan, it looks like it is abandoned, so I can forget about it.
- NetSqlAzMan looks like something we could use, but I'm not sure if it is possible to provide users from external source (not from AD)
- Custom role membership provider - would like to avoid it, since it would require to write whole management interface.

It could be some commercial product also. Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

The .NET framework already provides all the building blocks with the various Membership Providers.

There is a walkthrough in MSDN on how to implement membership with login and user management:

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I would like to avoid custom membership provider. It does not provide any management interface. I'm looking for something complete, more like AzMan but actively supported with good management interface. Could be commercial product also.